# SQLite Parameter Issue with Guids

Tags: c#, sql, database, sqlite

I am having issues with getting Guids to match in SQLite (0.4.8) when using parameters, when I use something like `userGuid = 'guid here'` it works, but `userGuid = @GuidHere` it does not.  Anyone have any ideas?

Create:

```
CREATE TABLE Users
(
   UserGuid TEXT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, 
   FirstName TEXT, 
   LastName TEXT
)
```

Sample Data:

```
INSERT INTO Users (UserGuid, FirstName, LastName) 
VALUES ('e7bf9773-8231-44af-8d53-e624f0433943', 'Bobby', 'Bobston')
```

Delete Statement (Working):

```
DELETE FROM Users WHERE UserGuid = 'e7bf9773-8231-44af-8d53-e624f0433943'
```

Delete Statement (Not Working):

```
DELETE FROM Users WHERE UserGuid = @UserGuid
```

Here is a C# program showing my issue:

```
using System;
using System.Data.SQLite;

namespace SQLite_Sample_App
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Do();
            Console.Read();
        }

        static void Do()
        {
            using(SQLiteConnection MyConnection = new SQLiteConnection("Data     Source=:memory:;Version=3;New=True"))
            {
                MyConnection.Open();
                SQLiteCommand MyCommand = MyConnection.CreateCommand();
                MyCommand.CommandText = @"
                    CREATE TABLE Users
                    (
                       UserGuid TEXT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, 
                       FirstName TEXT, 
                       LastName TEXT
                    );

                    INSERT INTO Users (UserGuid, FirstName, LastName) 
                    VALUES ('e7bf9773-8231-44af-8d53-e624f0433943', 'Bobby', 'Bobston');
                    ";
                MyCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

                MyCommand.CommandText = "SELECT Count(*) FROM Users WHERE UserGuid = 'e7bf9773-8231-44af-8d53-e624f0433943'";
                Console.WriteLine("Method One: {0}", MyCommand.ExecuteScalar());

                MyCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserGuid", new Guid("e7bf9773-8231-44af-8d53-e624f0433943"));
                MyCommand.CommandText = "SELECT Count(*) FROM Users WHERE UserGuid = @UserGuid";
                Console.WriteLine("Method Two: {0}", MyCommand.ExecuteScalar());                    
            }
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:

Well it seems that the AddParamWithValue translates to a 16byte rep of a Guid so I guess I really do have to translate all guids to strings first... kinda annoying.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try just passing the string of the GUID to your AddWithValue call, rather than the GUID object.

So instead of

```
MyCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(
    "@UserGuid", new Guid("e7bf9773-8231-44af-8d53-e624f0433943"));
```

Do this:

```
MyCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(
    "@UserGuid", "e7bf9773-8231-44af-8d53-e624f0433943");
```